# JavaScript Iterating List of Objects

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer, skyscanner

I'm writing a scraper for Skyscanner just for fun. What I'm trying to do is to iterate through the list of all listings, and for each listing, extract the URL.

[image]

What I've done so far is getting the listing  $("div[class^='FlightsResults_dayViewItems']") which returns

[image]

but I'm not sure how to iterate through the returned object and get the URL (/transport/flight/bos...). The pseudo code that I have is

```
for(listings in $("div[class^='FlightsResults_dayViewItems']")) {
     go to class^='EcoTickerWrapper_itineraryContainer' 
          go to class^='FlightsTicket_container'
               go to class^='FlightsTicket_link' and get the href and save in an array
}
```

How would I go about doing this?
Side-note, I'm using cheerio and jquery.

Update:
I figured out the CSS selector is

```
$("div[class^='FlightsResults_dayViewItems'] > div:nth-child(at_index_i) > div[class^='EcoTicketWrapper_itineraryContainer'] > div[class^='FlightsTicket_container'] > a[class^='FlightsTicket_link']").href
```

Now, I'm trying to figure out how to loop through the listing and apply the selector for each listing in the loop.

Also, it seems like not including the div:nth-child(at_index_i) won't work. Is there a way around this?

```
$("div[class^='FlightsResults_dayViewItems'] > div:nth-child(3) > div[class^='EcoTicketWrapper_itineraryContainer'] > div[class^='FlightsTicket_container'] > [class^='FlightsTicket_link']").attr("href")

"/transport/flights/bos/cun/210301/210331/config/10081-2103010815--32733-0-10803-2103011250|10803-2103311225--31722-1-10081-2103312125?adults=1&adultsv2=1&cabinclass=economy&children=0&childrenv2=&destinationentityid=27540602&inboundaltsenabled=false&infants=0&originentityid=27539525&outboundaltsenabled=false&preferdirects=false&preferflexible=false&ref=home&rtn=1"


$("div[class^='FlightsResults_dayViewItems'] > div[class^='EcoTicketWrapper_itineraryContainer'] > div[class^='FlightsTicket_container'] > [class^='FlightsTicket_link']").attr("href")

undefined
```

Here's the function to iterate the listings and grab the URLs for each listing.

```
async function scrapeListingUrl(listingURL) {
  try {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(listingURL, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
    // await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle2" }); // Wait until page is finished loading before navigating
    console.log("Finished loading page.");

    const html = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML);
    fs.writeFileSync("./listing.html", html);

    const $ = await cheerio.load(html); // Inject jQuery to easily get content of site more easily compared to using raw js

    // Iterate through flight listings
    // Note: Using regex to match class containing "FlightsResults_dayViewItems" to get listing since actual class name contains nonsense string appended to end.
    const bookingURLs = $('a[class*="FlightsTicket_link"]')
      .map((i, elem) => console.log(elem.href))
      .get();

    console.log(bookingURLs);
    return bookingURLs;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Scrape flight url failed.");
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just as a reminder: _"You also agree not to use any unauthorized automated computer program, software agent, bot, spider or other software or application to scan, copy, index, sort or otherwise exploit our Services or Platforms or the data contained on them."_ ([Source](https://www.skyscanner.com/media/terms-of-service))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
const hrefs = $(selector).map((i, elem) => elem.href).get()
```

Looking at the code you are not using jQuery so above does not work. So you just need to use a basic selector that matches part of the class with querySelectorAll. And map is used to grab the hrefs.

```
const links = [...document.querySelectorAll('a[class*="FlightsTicket_link"]')]
    .map(l=>l.href)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for sharing. I'm actually working on the selector if you happen to have any experience with that? I included the problem towards the end of the post.

Comment: The map function works when I enter it in chrome developer tool, but when I paste the same code in my app, I end up with a bunch of undefined values. What I'm doing is 

const html = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML);
    fs.writeFileSync("./listing.html", html);

    const $ = await cheerio.load(html); 
    const bookingURLs = $('a[class*="FlightsTicket_link"]')
      .map((i, elem) => console.log(elem.href))
      .get();

I've attached the downloaded HTML here https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bjj5D39r3x/

Do you mind taking a look at it?

Comment: Well guess you are calling it before the content is loaded on the page.

Comment: Actually, I'll paste the full function in the post